# How to receive @Published var in main thread

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, property-wrapper

I keep the Model as a Published var in the ViewModel and Observe it from the View.

When the model process goes into a background thread, if you publish the model value, the Xcode thread checker will react.

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values ​​from the main thread (via operators like receive (on :)) on model updates.

Is issued.

```
@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
```

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var model = Model()
    var thisValue:String {
        return model.thisValue // I want to use this value in view
    }
```

```
struct Model {
    var thisValue:String = "value" // I want to change this value on background threads.
```

I'd like to know how to receive the model value in the main thread, but
I didn't quite understand and asked a question.

I would be very happy if you could tell me.

Comment: Option 1: Make your changes on the main thread (using `DispatchQueue.main.async` or similar. Option 2) Utilize Swift's new `@MainActor`. See: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/the-main-actor-attribute/

Comment: Observe by subscribing with `receive(on:)`.

Comment: Thank you. 
I added @MainActor to model and viewModel but it does not work.
And I can not use DispatchQueue.main.async, because my model is struct so struct can not capture self in closure.

And I do not know how to use receive(on:) with published var

Answer (score 4):

Like Matt mentioned above, you want to "subscribe" to the model value using .receive(on:) and .sink

Though I'm not sure how @StateObject comes into play, or if you need it.  The basic format I've seen used is:

```
class ViewModel {
    // this could be a computed property or...
    @Published var thisValue: SomeType
    // ...more viewModel logic that potentially changes the value of `thisValue`
}

class View: UIView {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    // in viewDidLoad start your subscription to the viewModel's published property
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.$thisValue
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] result in
                // do something with the result
            }
            .store(in: $cancellables)
    }
}
```

Also, if the result is something really simple like a String and all you want to do is set a labels text property, instead of using `.sink` you can use `.assign`

```
viewModel.$thisValue
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .assign(to: \.text, on: label)
    .store(in: $cancellables)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite get what you are trying to do. But if you are not happy with `DispatchQueue.main.async` you may try one of the following options:

### Combine

```
struct Model {
    var thisValue: String = "value"
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = Model()
    var thisValue: String {
        model.thisValue
    }
    func setThisValueInBackground() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            Just(Model(thisValue: "newValue")).receive(on: RunLoop.main).assign(to: &self.$model)
        }
    }
}
```

### Unpublish your `model` and use property observer on it instead

```
class ViewModelV2: ObservableObject {
    var model = Model() {
        didSet {
            thisValue = model.thisValue
        }
    }
    @Published private(set) var thisValue: String = ""
    func setThisValueInBackground() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.model = Model(thisValue: "newValue")
        }
    }
}
```